# Subscribing to another observable in doOnNext method

Tags: java, reactivex

I am using `ReactiveX 1` (cannot migrate to version 2).

It's just example of the problem, but say I want to `save` an entity using reactive `repository`. It returns an observable of saveResult, which is subscribed by layer above (e.g. controller).

But then if the `save` was successful, I need to send an `event`. Sending an event is also reactive and returns an `Observable`. I actually do not care about it's result (there are some logs, and that's it).

I have done it in following way, but it's look a bit ugly, because an `Observableception`. **Is there a way to do it cleaner?** I would be satisfied by some `Observable<T> peek(rx.functions.Func1<? super T, Observable<?> func)`, but I was unable to find it

```java
public Observable<Result<Entity>> save(Entity entity){
return entityRepository.saveEntity(entity) //Observable<Result<Entity>>
    .doOnNext(saveResult -> saveResult
        .ifSuccessful(entity -> sendEntityCreatedEvent(entity)) //Observable<Result<EntityCreatedEvent>>
            .subscribe()

}
```

Thank you,

Tyvrel

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could use a `flatMap` to run the save `Observable`, at least this way you don't break the Observable chain.

```
public Observable<Result<Entity>> save(Entity entity){
return entityRepository.saveEntity(entity) //Observable<Result<Entity>>
    .flatMap(saveResult -> saveResult
        .ifSuccessful(entity -> sendEntityCreatedEvent(entity)) //Observable<Result<EntityCreatedEvent>>
            .map(entity -> saveResult)
    )
}
```

Since you need the result from the previous `Observable` just map the result from this `Observable` to the old result.

Comment: Actually, I have to map to something when result is not successful, so it would look more like:
`return entityRepository.saveEntity(entity) //Observable<Result<Entity>>
    .flatMap(saveResult -> saveResult
            .map(entity -> sendEntityCreatedEvent(entity)
                .map(Optional::of) 
            .orElse(error -> Observable.just(Observable.empty())) //Observable<Result<EntityCreatedEvent>>
        .map(eventOptional -> saveResult) //Observable<Result<Entity>>
    )`
Unfortunately this is not really readable =(

Comment: To make it more readable, you could delegate the work to another method. Also I think you can just do `.orElse(error -> Observable.empty())`. I only tried to fix the problem of the `subscribe()` inside `doOnNext()` which I think is a code smell, you can't dispose it.